# Anyway to clear brush from settlements?

Tags: fallout-4

There is leafy brush (or scrub bushes, or in some cases hedges) in most settlements. It seems to be mere scenery, but it overlaps and sticks through buildings and other settlement objects.

It seems impossible to get rid of; you certainly can't scrap it. Anyway to remove it?

I would prefer a non-console solution, if one exists.

Comment: Does the scrub block buildings? If not, does it clip through the floor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to remove it without using the console. With the console, I believe you should be able to open the console, click on the scrub to select it, and type "disable" in the console. I've never used this on shrubs, but it's worked on everything else I've tried it on.

Another option, while not removing it, would be to use the platform floors or the foundations to raise all your buildings above the level of the scrub.

Comment: Disable only works on instanced objects in the game, which won't include most of the scenery, structures, etc. unfortunately.  It does work on some objects though, like doors, gates, wires, strung up bodies, etc.

Comment: Aww, dang. Alright. I used it on the tesla arcs in the armory, and hoped it would work on these too.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few mods that help with that. I use [Spring Cleaning](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4640/).

> Spring Cleaning allows for the removal of trash and clutter objects originally unable to be scrapped within settlements.

A video of Spring Cleaning in action:

Comment: Doesn't look like this is available on consoles yet, unfortunately.